# Not understanding method types

Tags: java

Teaching myself Java and I came across a confusing part about method types/return types?

For example what does the `<U>` right after the `public` represent in the method below? How can it return a type of `<U>` and `List<U>`?

```
public <U> IList<U> map(IFunc<T, U> f) {
    return new ConsList<U>(f.apply(this.first), this.rest.map(f));
}
```

Comment: `U` is a generic type.  You should have a read of the Oracle trail on this, it is very informative: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called as a *Type Paremeter*. It represents a generic class that is representing within that `map` method. What I meant by generic class is, any class you can come up with. It can be `MyHouse.java`, `MyCar.java`, `String.java`, etc

`IList<U>` is, it's a `IList` that contains `U` type objects.

Comment: So lets say if I changed `<U>` to `<Books>` the map method would return a list of books?

Comment: @CtrlAltDelete yesm exactly